# Why: $2^{n+1} = 1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n}2^i$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, exponentiation

I was doing some messing around on excel to answer this brain teaser:

*In autumn the amount of leaves falling from a tree get doubled after every hour. The tree is leafless after 9 days. How many hours does it take until half of all leaves have fallen down?*

**WARNING: Brain teaser answer below, if you want to work it out yourself.**

On Excel I was simulating doubling the number of leaves falling every hour, finding the cumulative leaves that have fallen, and then the proportion of the total leaves that have fallen (note 9 days = 216 hrs):

```
hour    leaves falling   cumlative      proportion of leaves
        that hour                       that have fallen
1       1                1              9.49557E-66
2       2                3              2.84867E-65
3       4                7              6.6469E-65
4       8                15             1.42434E-64
5       16               31             2.94363E-64
.       .                .              .
211     1.6455E+63       3.29101E+63    0.03125
212     3.29101E+63      6.58202E+63    0.0625
213     6.58202E+63      1.3164E+64     0.125
214     1.3164E+64       2.63281E+64    0.25
215     2.63281E+64      5.26561E+64    0.5
216     5.26561E+64      1.05312E+65    1
```

It takes 215 hours for the first half to fall, and then the second half all fall in the final hour.

I can see this, but don't fully understand why this is.

What I can see is the second column is just the series $2^n$, where $n$ is the $hour-1$, and that the third column is one less than the next $2^n$, i.e.:
$$
2^{n+1} = 1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n}2^i
$$

No doubt that, at hour 215, this 1 before the sum is so insignificant that:
$$
2^{n+1} \approx \sum_{i=0}^{n}2^i
$$
for large $n$. 
I can see therefore that, for all intents and purposes, half of the leaves do fall in the last hour.

My question is, why does:
$$
2^{n+1} = 1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n}2^i
$$
Is there any intuitive logic that can explain this? Or, if not, a mathematical proof?

Answer (score 4):

From the sum of geometric progress:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n 2^i=\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{2 - 1}=2^{n+1}-1$$

Adding $1$ yields the result.

Intuitively you can look at one element at the time:

$$1+\sum_{i=0}^n 2^i=$$
$$1+1+2+4+8+...+2^n=$$
$$2+2+4+8+...+2^n=$$
$$4+4+8+...+2^n=$$
$$8+8+...+2^n=$$
$$2^n+2^n=2^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Binary arithmetic:

$2^{n+1}=1000.....00$ $(n+1)$ zeroes, altogether $(n+2)$ digits.

$\sum_{i=0}^{n}2^i= 1111.....11$, $(n+1)$dig. $1$.

Adding in the binary system:

$0111.....11111 +$

$0000.....00001$

$--------------$

$1000.....00000$ $(n+2)$ digits.